# How to keep up to date master in B remote if it differs from A only with build files in each module?

Tags: git

How to keep up to date master in B remote if it differs from A only with build files in each module?

I tried to use two remotes and one with two URLs.

So we have remotes

```
a
b
```

Difference between them

```
build file any_1.xml in first module
build file any_2.xml in second module, etc.
```

OR (!)
Remotes

```
r
```

URLs for this one remote

```
a
b
```

Branches for both "OR (!)" cases

```
master
```

Please, provide, full and tested git steps, this will help to me and other developers.

Expected

```
Identical master bracnhes, except any_1.xml, any_2.xml, etc.
```